# Pytest fails on Travis: cannot find main package

Tags: travis-ci, pytest

I recently made a large swath of changes to a Python 3 project on Github, largely documentation and docstrings.

The tests pass locally, but when I push the branch to Github, Travis CI fails:

```
$ pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 342, in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
KeyError: local('/home/travis/build/scossu/lakesuperior')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 373, in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
KeyError: local('/home/travis/build/scossu/lakesuperior/conftest.py')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 379, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 668, in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.5.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 212, in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
  File "/home/travis/build/scossu/lakesuperior/conftest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lakesuperior.config_parser import test_config
ImportError: No module named 'lakesuperior.config_parser'
ERROR: could not load /home/travis/build/scossu/lakesuperior/conftest.py
The command "pytest" exited with 4.
```

`lakesuperior` is the main application package.

My `.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.5"
  - "3.6"
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - coilmq&
script:
- pytest tests
```

The only thing that I think may have affected the import issue is that I added some `__init__.py` files to subpackages in order for Sphinx to discover API docs. I am not sure how that may have messed up CI though.

I verified that the previous commit passes all tests as it used to.

Has anybody encountered this scenario before? Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. I fixed it by removing the `__init__.py` file from the top level directory. See [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules).